# show that $F(H)$ in $B(H)$ whit norm operator closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

if $H$ is Hilbert space, and $F(H)$ finite rank operators,
I will show $F(H)$ closed with $B(H)$, I have tried ti prove it and some techniques have been applied but unfortunately I couldn't  do it
Any hints would be appreciated
I need help in proof
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Consider diagonal operators acting on $\ell^2$ with the sequence of diagonal entries going to zero. Such examples will provide a bounded operator on a Hilbert space that is a norm limit of finite rank operators but is not itself a finite rank operator